# Append one array values as key value pair to another array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays both guaranteed to be the same length. The two arrays are of the following structures

array1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 841052
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1613197
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 401
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1648966
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1656857
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 1
        )
....
....
)
```

array2

```
Array

(
    [0] => 5/20/2019
    [1] => 7/7/2019
    [2] => 12/16/2018
    ...
    ...
)
```

How do I append every value of array2 as a key value pair to array1 to get the following array. The key name can be whatever I just chose date.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 841052
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 1
            [date] => 5/20/2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1613197
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 401
            [date] => 7/7/2019
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1648966
            [store] => 11
            [position] => 1
            [date] => 12/16/2018
        )
)
...
...
...
```

I have tried

`array_push($array1, $array2);`

It just pushed it to the last element of the array. I thought of using two `foreach` loops but couldn't get ti to work. Is there a built in php function that will do this, or do I have to do it in loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just walk `$array1` and modify each sub-array by adding the new key and the value of `$array2` with the same key:

```
array_walk($array1, function(&$v, $k) use($array2) { $v['date'] = $array2[$k]; });
```

Comment: getting a `array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members` error. Using PHP 5.3.3 if that matters

Comment: Damn, I started with map but it should be `array_walk`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver This answer is better than mine. Only doubt, if it does not correspond the number of elements could give error.

Comment: @ees3 This is better for you!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    $array1 = array(array("id" => 841052, "store" => "11", "position" => "1"), array("id" => 1613197, "store" => "11", "position" => "401"),);
    $array2 = array("5/20/2019", "7/7/2019");
    foreach ($array1 as $index => $valuearray1) {
        if (array_key_exists($index, $array2)) {
            $array1[$index]["date"] = $array2[$index];
        }
    }
    var_dump($array1);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of $valuearray1 in this example?