# Turn each array item into key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. One is a list of colors, the second is an associative array of key value pairs. My objective is to take the key value pairs from the associative array and make them a sub-array of each item in the colors array. Searching SO has gotten me various adjacent issues, but not the one I'm having specifically. Here are two example arrays, and then **$final** is what I want to achieve:

```
$colors = ['#eea845', '#64A0B4', '#003c50', '#FF5568', '#eee', '#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#f0ad4e', '#d9534f'];

$test = [
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val2',
  'key3' => 'val3',
  'key4' => 'val4',
  'key5' => 'val5',
  'key6' => 'val6',
  'key7' => 'val7',
  'key8' => 'val8',
  'key9' => 'val9',
];

$final = [
   '#eea845' => [
      'name' => 'key1',
      'value' => 'val1',
   ],
   '#64A0B4' => [
      'name' => 'key2',
      'value' => 'val2',
   ],
   etc.....
]
```

I've been looking at **array_walk**, **array_map**, and trying to figure out how to combine **for** and **foreach** loops. I looked at the answer given here ([Append one array values as key value pair to another array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695836/append-one-array-values-as-key-value-pair-to-another-array-php)) but I'm not sure how to use it on an already existing array and be able to get the index of each. For example, that solution uses `array_walk($array1, function(&$v, $k) use($array2) { $v['date'] = $array2[$k]; });` but I need to have the values from $array2 be added to already existing items in $array1, and while I tried doing `function($i, $v, $k)` with **$i** being the index inside $array1, that didn't work, $i being undefined.

I'm stumped and not sure where to look next. How would you

```
return $colors[$i] => 
  [
   'name' => $test[$key], 
   'value' => $test[$name] 
  ]
```

?

(For context, I am using this to get values to input into a Twig template, and this looks like the best way to do it for that half of the problem. But if it's too difficult on this side...)

Comment: array_map then array_combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. One way is to use `foreach` on the associative array, so you get key and value in separate variables, and to use `next()` to get the corresponding value from the first (indexed) array:

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $final[current($colors)] = ["name" => $key, "value" => $value];
    next($colors);
}
```

In the rare event you had already used `next()` on `$colors`, you'll have to call `reset($colors)` before starting this loop.

Comment: Or with `array_shift()` if mutating/destroying the `$colors` array is tolerable. https://3v4l.org/G96iD  Or without destroying the `$colors` while maintaining a counter. https://3v4l.org/eMmUf

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a combination of `foreach()` using the below logic:

1. Check if both the arrays have same length.
2. Use `foreach` to walk through the array and fill in the final array.
3. I am not good in this point, but I use a `$count` to keep track of the index. You can use cursors like `next($colors)` and `current($colors)`, but I am not sure.

```php
<?php
$colors = [
    '#eea845', '#64A0B4', '#003c50', '#FF5568', '#eee', '#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#f0ad4e', '#d9534f'
];

$test = [
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val2',
  'key3' => 'val3',
  'key4' => 'val4',
  'key5' => 'val5',
  'key6' => 'val6',
  'key7' => 'val7',
  'key8' => 'val8',
  'key9' => 'val9',
];

if (count($colors) == count($test)) {
    $count = 0;
    $finalOne = array();
    foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        $finalOne[$colors[$count]] = [
            "name" => $key,
            "value" => $value
        ];
        $count++;
    }
    print_r($finalOne);
} else {
    echo "Arrays are of not same length.";
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [#eea845] => Array
        (
            [name] => key1
            [value] => val1
        )

    [#64A0B4] => Array
        (
            [name] => key2
            [value] => val2
        )

    [#003c50] => Array
        (
            [name] => key3
            [value] => val3
        )

    [#FF5568] => Array
        (
            [name] => key4
            [value] => val4
        )

    [#eee] => Array
        (
            [name] => key5
            [value] => val5
        )

    [#5cb85c] => Array
        (
            [name] => key6
            [value] => val6
        )

    [#5bc0de] => Array
        (
            [name] => key7
            [value] => val7
        )

    [#f0ad4e] => Array
        (
            [name] => key8
            [value] => val8
        )

    [#d9534f] => Array
        (
            [name] => key9
            [value] => val9
        )

)
```

Working Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73fb63fab8ccbdb6f73c795572ae51a0d98acdb4

Comment: Please use 3v4l.org as your demo'ing sandbox.  The UX on mobile devices is abysmal on sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: @mickmackusa This is the first time I am hearing about 3v4l.org. Thank you so much. ❤️